# How do I do this with switch instead of if esle?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am taking my first programming course and the assignment was to redo a previous program (this one) using a switch statement.  I thought that switch was just used to compare single characters.

The program essentially just receives a string and counts numbers, letters, other characters, and total characters.....

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[50];
    int i;
    int total = 0;
    int letters = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int others = 0;    

    cout << "Enter a continuous string of characters with no blank spaces" << endl;
    cout << "(example: aBc1234!@#$%)" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter your string: ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << endl;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != 0)
    {
        if ((s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') || (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z'))
            letters++;
        else if ((s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
            numbers++;
        else
            others++;
        i++;
        total++;
    }

    cout << letters << " letters" << endl;
    cout << numbers << " numbers" << endl;
    cout << others << " other characters" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are "only" 52 letters and 10 digits, you can list them all in switch statement.

Comment: What a dreadful assignment.

Comment: I know, the teacher is not very good so I'm relieved to have discovered this site.  He expects us to spend 10-15 hours a week figuring out how to make it work with minimal information.  I talked to the department head today and they are cancelling the class and allowing students a refund of money if they want it but I need this class for graduation next year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this particular situation `if/else` is the best way (as said by @zenith) but if you wished do to it with switch statements you would do

```
switch(s[i])
{
    case `0`:
    case '1':
    case '2':
    //repeat for '3'-'8'
    case '9':
        //do whatever you want when it is a digit here
        break;
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    case 'B':
    case 'b':
    //repeat for 'C'-'y'
    case 'Z':
    case 'z':
        //do whatever you want when it is a letter
        break;
    default:
        //do whatever you want when it was not a letter or a digit
        break;
}
```

When a `case` matches in a `switch` statement, everything up to the corresponding `break` is executed - that's how you can group cases like this

Comment: Where can I read to find out how and why 'i' works in all of this?  I don't really understand the logic of declaring i as an integer and then putting it in like     s[i]

Comment: @TaylorClark `s` is an array of characters; `s[i]` obtains the ***i***th character from `s`.

Comment: @AtlasC1 Thanks.  So since I set i = 0 does that mean that the first ith character is nonexistent as in the first loop analyzes nothing ?

Comment: @TaylorClark in C++, arrays are indexed from 0 to size-1. So, `s[0]` is actually the first element in the array. For example, if you have `char s[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };`, then `s[0]` is 'a', `s[1]` is 'b', and `s[2]` is 'c'. If you try to access an index outside the array bounds (e.g., `s[3]` or `s[-1]`) bad things will happen—even though they might not be apparent at first—so make sure you don't do that!

Comment: @AtlasC1 Thanks for the explination.  So if the last index of array is ' s[-1]' how does the program I posted above end up at 0 in order to quit the 'while' loop

Comment: @AtlasC1 sorry to bug you man.  I think the part I'm having trouble understanding is how the program knows to run until `s[i] = 0` considering we are assinging `0` before the `while` loop

Comment: !!!!  NEVERMIND I get it.  it stops once the string ends which would be a null /0 or 0 and the 0 we are assigning is (as you said) the position of the character from 0 to null  ...  Thank you for taking your time to help me out

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't. `switch` statements work based on `==`, not `<=` / `>=` / `<` / `>`.

The `case`s in a `switch` statement must be constant expressions. You'd have to make a separate `case` for each character.

There are situations where `switch` is a better solution. But this is not one of those situations. Here `if` and `else` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need a mapping from all the characters of interest onto the behaviors.

```
enum char_category { OTHER, LETTER, NUMBER };
unsigned char mapping[256];

memset(mapping, OTHER, sizeof mapping);

for( char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ++ch ) mapping[ch] = NUMBER;
for( char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch ) mapping[ch] = mapping[tolower(ch)] = LETTER;
```

Then you can use a jump table:

```
switch ( mapping[s[i]] )
{
    case NUMBER:
        break;
    case LETTER:
        break;
    case OTHER:
        break;
}
```

Or you could completely skip the conditionals:

```
int count[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

count[mapping[s[i]]]++;

letters = count[LETTER];
numbers = count[NUMBER];
other = count[OTHER];
```

Note that the work of setting up the mapping is only justified if you have more than a few dozen input characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(s[i]) {
    case '0':
    ...
    case '9': numbers++; break;
    default: {
        switch(toupper(s[i])) {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            ...
            case 'Z': letters++; break;
            default: others++;
        }
     }
}
```